# Whether particular li with a specific text exists inside a ul using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code

like

```
<ul id="uploadedfiles">
   <li>
       A_001
   </li>
   <li>
       B_001
   </li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to insert a new li but i want to check that something that whether a li with a text say A_ exist in that ul. If it exists than remove the older and add the new li.

Say if i add C_001 it is added with no issue

But if i add A_002 then it replace the A_001 with A_002.

Please provide the code for the same if possible.

Any help is appreciated!

Added:

The real data in li have text like control20_a.jpg , control21_b.jpg .....
Then when adding a new li say control20_c.jpg the code  must replace control20_a.jpg. But add a new li if it does not exists

Comment: jQuery has great documentation: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: @AndyRose i am not so good in jquery. This complete html is going to be injected from a custom control in c#. So i have no idea what could be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not very idiomatic jQuery, but it seems to do the job.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/XZjBb/)

```
var add = function(entry) {
    var match = $('#uploadedfiles li:contains(' + entry.slice(0, entry.indexOf('_')) + ')');
    if (match.length > 0) {
        match.text(entry);
    } else {
        $('#uploadedfiles').append($('<li>' + entry + '</li>'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would add a class to the li (like `<li class="a">` and `<li class="b">`
2. When adding the new LI i would strip the first char of the name and find the LI
3. If no li, I would create it else change the innerHTML for the new one.

Good luck

UPDATE:
if the elements are from 001 to 002 etc you could do

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
    var firstChar = $(this).text().substring(0,1);
    var removeElms = $("ul li:contains('"+firstChar+"'):not(:last)");
    removeElms.remove();
});
```

Comment: The li is going to be added dynamically from a custom control and they can be hundreds too. Can there is some easier way. Doesnt matter about performance.

Comment: so at the end you have something like `<li>a_001</li><li>a_002</li><li>b_001</li>` etc.?

Comment: Yes, and then when adding new li i need to check the all previous ones before adding a new one

Comment: Actually i think my question is not clear. i may have variable string before the _ and after it too. Means i may have li that is <li>control20_a.gif</li><li>control21.jpg</li>